# Kafka is not receiving messages after adding new consumer group using kafka clients java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka working fine when we push new messages but not working if we are reading old queued messages after adding new consumer group.

Note : The problem is only existing with the below java configuration of Kafka else its working fine if we use spring boot.

```java
public class KafkaConsumerListener implements Runnable {

    private List<String> topics;
    private Consumer<String, String> consumer;

    public KafkaConsumerListener(List<String> topics) {
        this.topics = topics;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Consumer topics " + topics);
            consumer = KafkaConsumer.create(topics);
             while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                System.out.println("POLL " + records);
                records.forEach(record -> {
                    System.out.println("Payload: " + record.value() + ", Offset: " + record.offset() + " Topic: "
                            + record.topic() + ", By ThreadID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    KafkaPayloadDelegator.delegate(record.topic(), record.value());
                    consumer.commitSync();
                });
            
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }

}


public class KafkaConsumer {
    

    public static Consumer<String, String> create(List<String> topic) {
        
        ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("applicationResource");
        System.out.println("SCM_Kafka Servers are running at "+messages.getString("kafka.servers"));
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, messages.getString("kafka.servers"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, messages.getString("kafka.group.id"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        final Consumer<String, String> consumer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(topic);
        System.out.println("consumer create ");
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

**Starting kafka**

```java
    List<String> topics = Arrays.asList(messages.getString("kafka.consumer.topic").split(","));
    KafkaConsumerListener kafka = new KafkaConsumerListener(topics);
    new Thread(kafka).start();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, after you change `kafka.group.id`, you get no messages?

Comment: correct after changing the group id it should start consuming from the beginning.

Comment: And those records that you're trying to read have not expired? Your code here is basically the same as using `kafka-console-consumer --topic T --group G --from-beginning`, so does that work?